# Polymer get attributes marker selected

Tags: google-maps, polymer

I have a question about get position (latitude and longitude) from the marker I have click on.

```
<google-map-marker latitude="46" longitude="-46" click-events="true" on-google-map-marker-click="clickDestination"></google-map-marker>

clickDestination: function(marker) {
    console.log('click sur carte');
    console.log(typeof marker); //Object
    console.log(this.getPosition().lat()); //not a function
},
```

Comment: Does `marker.getPosition` works any better?

Comment: It's undefined with marker.getPosition

Comment: Well, I don't how this works but could you inspect the properties of your `marker` object?

Comment: Object { map: Array[1], clickEvents: Array[1], icon: Array[1], mouseEvents: Array[1], zIndex: Array[1], longitude: Array[2], latitude: Array[2], animation: Array[1], open: Array[1] }

Comment: Why not access the properties directly? `marker.latitude` and `marker.longitude`? According to the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map?active=google-map-marker) there is not `.getPosition()` function.

Comment: is still undefine var pos = marker.latitude;
console.log(pos);

Comment: else if I could try to getAttribut of the selected marker but how can I do that in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter passed into the `clickDestination` function is not the marker but the `event` fired. The `target` property on the event object will be the marker that was clicked on. You can then access the properties on that marker like so:

```
<template>
    <google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fit-to-markers>
      <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892"
          draggable="true" title="Go Giants!" click-events="true" 
          on-google-map-marker-click="clickDestination">
      </google-map-marker>
    </google-map>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "map-test",
        clickDestination: function (event) {
            var longitude = event.target.longitude;
            var longitude = event.target.longitude;
        }
    });
</script>
```